# erlang dbg module is not working included in relx

Tags: erlang, dbg

I have Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.3.5] and runtime_tools included in release, `rel/reltool.config.script:  [tools, runtime_tools];`, but when I trying using dbg I got

```
error:  dbg:tracer().
** exception error: undefined function dbg:tracer/0
```

Looks like dbg module is not included to my application

```
(ejabberd@localhost)4> m(dbg).
** exception error: undefined function dbg:module_info/0
```

I want use [erlang easy profiler](https://github.com/virtan/eep), that I successfully used on erl 16

Does anyone faced with this problem?